# Multivariable for loop with conditional increment/decrement

Tags: java, for-loop, conditional-statements

Is there a neat way to do something like this?

```
        for (int left = 0, right = height.length - 1;
         left < height;
         height[left] < height[right] ? left++ : right--)
```

I will be increasing left only if the condition is true. Otherwise, right will be decremented. I know I can do this inside the for loop and change the whole structure of the for loop around. But I was just curious if it was possible to have conditionals inside the for loop decrement/increment block.

Comment: Personally I'd use a while loop `while (left < right)`, and add `if (height[left] < height[right]` condition in the while loop.

Comment: Yeah, I know that's an option. I was just curious if there was something like this. It seems more elegant to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, but I don't see why you would want to. However, to make it work, we just need to make sure that the loop uses valid statements.

Remember that a `for` loop consists of:

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

Your last section (the `increment`) is not a valid statement:

```
height[left] < height[right] ? left++ : right--
```

But we can make it valid by assigning the result to a dummy value:

```
dummyValue = height[left] < height[right] ? left++ : right--
```

And the working result of a one line `for` loop with no contents:

```
int someValue  = 0;
for (int left = 0, right = height.length - 1; left < height.length; someValue = height[left] < height[right] ? left++ : right--);
```

Or for the sake of showing that it works you can add some debugging:

```
int someValue  = 0;
for (int left = 0, right = height.length - 1; left < height.length; someValue = height[left] < height[right] ? left++ : right--){
    //Debugging to show that it works
    System.out.println("Left: "+left+" Right: "+right);
}
```

Example output when height[] = `{2,1,6,3,4,5}` before it throws an exception:

```
L: 0 R: 5
L: 1 R: 5
L: 2 R: 5
L: 2 R: 4
L: 2 R: 3
L: 2 R: 2
L: 2 R: 1
L: 2 R: 0
```

Note that `left` and `right` are not accessible outside/after the `for` loop, so this usage has absolutely no meaning other than updating the value of `someValue` which has little use?

If you want to make this sort of one line `for` loop useful then change values that are declared prior to the loop, or have the loop call a method. For example below we create a method `someMethod` that replaces `height[left] < height[right]` and returns the result of it, but we can also perform an action in the method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int height[] = new int[]{...};
    int someValue = 0;
    //Call a method that does the any work we need
    for (int left = 0, right = height.length - 1; left < height.length; someValue = someMethod(height, left, right) ? left++ : right--);
}

//The method we call
static boolean someMethod(int[] height, int left, int right){
    //Some action here
    //Note that edits left and right here will not be reflected in the for loop
    //...
    
    //Return the original check
    return height[left] < height[right];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`For` loop is more suitable when you know no of execution times. `While` loop is more suitable when loop execution breaks based on some condition other than no of execution.

As [@Haoliang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19322223/haoliang), suggests while is more suitable in this case vs for loop.

Here slightly different `For` loop version.

```
for (int left = 0, right = height.length - 1; left < height; ) {

    height[left] < height[right] ? left++ : right--;
}
```

Alternative `while-loop` version, which I think is less clutter

```
int left = 0, right = height.length - 1;
while ( left < height ) {
    height[left] < height[right] ? left++ : right--;
}
```